# Android ActionBarCompat Not working from the start

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-actionbar-compat

OK, I have been wanting to try the new ActionBarCompat, however, I am not able to run my programs in the emulator.

I have been trying to implement the following: http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-how-to-use.

and have been stuck on basically the first part. However, working with the author of that content, I was able to get further as I was not **adding the project under sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat folder** like stated. However, I still think that might be the reason I cannot do this...

More detail can be found here: http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-how-to-use/#comment-43

Basically, on my first attempt, I just created an Android project, and changed the source code as indicated. **Code would not run on the emulator.** So I went back to the original code, and that ran on the emulator.

Checked online, found out I might need to add the \extras\android\support\v7\appcompat folder as a library to the project I am building. So I added that and a new android project was created. There were build errors from the start, but I failed at trying to add it as a library to my project, and deleted it....thinking this was way overboard.

After back and forth chats with author of linked website, I found out I had to do that overboard thing.

So I tried the following link to the T:  (I cannot post more than 2 links due to low repuation...I will add this link as a comment below)

However, Eclipse would not allow me to add the appcompat Existing **Android** Project...but it did allow me to add the appcompat Existing (**General**) Project. I think this may be some of the problems??

Right now, I cannot run the project at all. Eclipse is showing a red exclamation mark on the project folder, but all the code seems to be fine. So I don't know what to do now...I recreated this project several times over, and this one was the one where I knew what to do...and I am still getting problems

So...

I decided to move to Android Studio...updated the IDE, updated the SDK manager to include the new support library, and other things. Created a new project, added to the build.gradle file as shown in the link provided below in the comment. I ran the ant build, and then built the project...tried to import the right things to allow ActionBarActivity, but I could not get that far.

I can import

```
"android.support.v7.*"
"android.support.vy.R"    // and all folders within
```

but nothing allows me to add ActionBarActivity, and I don't know why.

FYI, I guess I would prefer a solution to Ecplise, as it seems like I actually got somewhere with it.

Comment: Here is the link from Android that I followed: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Comment: Try following these [instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#)

Comment: Maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429959/2556111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best example to use is from here, and I would follow it closely. I had similiar issues when I first came across this. Problem was I misunderstood what I needed to do

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Comment: Please quote or summarize the relevant linked content. SO is meant to be a content provider, not a content aggregator.