# How to resolve the error "No resource found that matches the given name" when adding library v7 AppCompat in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar-compat

I have a project target to API Level 10 and i want to implement the new ActionBar support library.
After follow all the instrutions in the [Support Library Setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html), when adding the library to my project I came across with dozens of error messages like this:

`android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.....`

OK, i know that they are many answers to this question, but, after trying all the more obvious, i still could not solve the error.
I kept searching and found the cause, which is not so obvious, at least for newbies like me.
My intent is provide a full answer to help all those who are like me and do not master all the secrets of the Android development.

Comment: I get errors like this unless both my project & support library target the *latest* version of Android. I'd rather target a lower version like you are doing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is what you have to do for use the ActionBar support library correctly.

Follow the instructions in the [Support Library Setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) - Adding libraries with resources.
One thing that can bring some doubt is add the library to your aplicattion project:

(1) In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
(2) At the left pane select Android.
(3) At th bottom of the right pane click **Add**
(4) Select the library project android-support-v7-appcompat and click **OK**.
Click **OK** to close the properties window.

If you not get any of the errors I mentioned it´s all done.

However if you are like me, you dont´t followed the advice of Android team that suggests you always compile your source using the latest SDK, you get the error.

The error ocurrs because my Project Build Target was Android 2.3.3 and need to be at lest 3.0.
It was not immediately clear to me because of the fact that I'm specifically developing for Android 2.3.3 and I'm using support libraries.

OK, I hope this helps.

Comment: Care to explain how to do it without eclipse?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899318/adding-libs-with-resources-via-command-line

Comment: In Intellij IDEA, you need to go into `Project Structure` and set your project SDK version for Facebook.

Answer (score 4):

You should add that support library to your project. To add:

Right click on project, then go to :

properties > Java Build Path > Libraries

here **Add External JARs...**

add android-support-v7-appcompat.jar (path/to/sdk/**extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs**)

Additionally you also have to copy that jar to libs folder of your project, if it is not there  automatically.

and you should use the `@style/Theme.AppCompat` theme for your application for support-v7 to be working

Comment: That don't work if Project Build Target are below Android 3.0. The solution is Project Build Target to Android 3.0 or higher and there is no need to add the library to Java build path

Comment: @ramaral, I think support-v7 library supports API 7 and higher. You can refer to [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: 16, Yes I read this and is because this that i took me so long to find that I could only eliminate the error when target my application to Android 3.0

Answer (score 0):

also keep one thing in mind you should change min sdk version to 11 if you want to support("android:windowActionBar")property in your project.