# Error in Import Support V7

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

Good afternoon.
How are you.

Can you help me please, I'm trying to import the library support v7 - appcompat but present an error in the folders Values V-11 and Values V-14.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBDQ4.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/B91ic.png)

```
<!-- Progress Bar -->

<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
       parent="android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
</style>

<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ProgressBar"
       parent="android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar">
</style>

<!-- AutoCompleteTextView styles (for SearchView) -->

<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Base.AutoCompleteTextView"
       parent="android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView">
</style>

<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.AutoCompleteTextView"
       parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
</style>
```

Thanks for your attention, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429959/2556111

Comment: Hello, this is the links of errors
http://imgur.com/2UUkYw3
http://imgur.com/N6ao1Gi
http://imgur.com/c63D3Of
http://imgur.com/LV4Db21
Thanks for your answer ramaral, but i try and i still with the problem.

Sorry for my bad english.