# Issue with support library setup as per android developer guide using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, manifest, android-support-library

I've been through all of the subjects and all over Internet to try solving this problem, but can't seem to find any solution.

Basically I've followed every step here [Support Library Setup - Adding libraries with resources](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res), but can't figure out the last one.

Add the library to your application project:

> 1. In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
> 2. In the Library pane, click **Add**.
> 3. Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat.
> 4. In the properties window, click OK.

Now the problem is in library pane I see multiple add options (Add JARs, Add External JARs, Add Variable, Add Library Add Class Folder and Add External Class Folder)

Can anyone give me a bit more detailed explanation what I actually need to add?

The only place I see only **Add** option is "Projects" pane.

Cheers,
DP

Comment: you need to referece the library project in your andorid project

Comment: Any chance to be more specific?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429959/2556111

Answer (score 1):

This is to add a library that u got to your android application. So you can publish your app with the library to use it.

Like `Actionbar sherlock`, `angEngine`, `admob` or any other library.
To let your application support it, you should add it to it's project first.

And best way is to choose `Add External JARS`, or anything you would like.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to do this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html#ApiLevel7

So yeah ActionBar is what I need.

so I've tried your suggestion and it fixed the coding part, great.

But problem now is the Manifest file I get "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light')"

on my manifest file

`<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >`

Comment: @DeadpoolDude have you referenced the library project in the way i mentioned in my post?

Comment: restart eclipse or clean project

Answer (score 1):

First import the library into your workspace (where your androi project is). Import the library to eclipse. It is found under `/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompact`.

Right click on your android project. Goto properties. Choose android. Click Add browse and add reference the same in your android project

Click add browse and add the library project

[image]

When you add it looks like below

[image]

Comment: that solved the warnings part, thank you very much

I have yet to test if action bar actually works on android 2.3 and above

cheers

Comment: @DeadpoolDude you need to extend `ActionBarActivity` and use Theme.AppCompact

Comment: @DeadpoolDude check this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Answer (score 0):

Do it the easy way : right click your project folder in the Package Explorer or Navigator, then look for Android Tools > Add Support Library. A dialog with open to ask you to accept the license. Accept, click Install, and you're good to go ;-)