# sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:44: error

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-support-library

I'm trying to add an Action Bar to my Android 2.3.3 project. I'm following step-by-step [the Support Library Setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library) explained in Android Developers, which is very clear.

So basically, I created my Support library project *android-support-v7-appcompat* and added it as a library reference to my actual project.

When I build my project, I get this bunch of error that I don't really understand !! Do u have any idea what's the issue here ??

```
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:122: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:125: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:133: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:137: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:141: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:44: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:64: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:72: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:76: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:104: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:108: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:112: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:116: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:84: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:92: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:96: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:100: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:159: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:161: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:153: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:156: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:147: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:167: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:171: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:175: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:186: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:190: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:194: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:200: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Title'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:204: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Title'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:216: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:225: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:224: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:44: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:67: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2013-12-11 17:28:09 - TabTest] C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:94: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
```

Comment: See this anwser http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429959/2556111. Last paragraph.

Comment: just noticed my target was 2.2 changing to 4.3 did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a bit of a stab in the dark here without code but I believe you are not referencing the parent correctly. Try;

```
@android:style/Theme....
```

or

```
@android:style/Widget....
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I appreciate ur answer !