# Android application compatiblity issue

Tags: android, compatibility, android-version

I have developed an android application using android sdk 4.4(KitKat). My application runs fine on android 4.0 and 4.4 but it crashes on android 2.3 and other versions. I have used android action bar and I have read somewhere that action bars are not supported in previous versions. I can not change this app as I have to hand it over to the client and I am out of time. I am unable to fix it. I need any solution so that it will be available and compatible for atleat 2.3 and above.

Comment: you can use AppCompat from the support library

Comment: @Raghunandan I have tried to add AppCompat but it contains error in style_base.xml and themes_base.xml. what to do ?

Comment: how did you reference the AppCompat library

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429959/2556111) may help you to configure AppCompat

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActionBarSherlock as it is compatible to Android 2.X:
http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: It would make more sense to use the v7 support libs. ABS was a good stop gap but now Google have released an official support library for ActionBar it seems better to go with that.

Comment: @Flat Eric I have tried to add AppCompat but it contains error in style_base.xml and themes_base.xml. what to do ?

Comment: @Rida: I have no experience with AppCompat, that's why I suggested ActionBarSherlock