# how do i add v7-appcompat library to my project?i have followed the steps on google developer site and its just importing v4 library

Tags: android, android-actionbar

**I am trying to add Support Library v7 to my clean android project as support library (with resources). I followed every instruction here: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download and android.support.v7.* package is not visible in my main project.**

I don't see any errors in Problems tab, app compiles and runs normally but i cannot import android.support.v7 package which apparently isn't in build path in main project. I went through instruction twice in clean projects/workspace. I cleaned project, restarted Eclipse and nothing... All resources from library project are unreachable too.

Comment: import the library project to workspace and then reference the same in your andrpid project.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429959/2556111