# Adding libs with resources via command line

Tags: android, command-line

I'm trying to accomplish http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res without using eclipse or gradle; however, the official documentation doesn't support that. For the last couple hours, I've been Googling everything I can think of, but I'm not finding any helpful information.

Specifically, I'm trying to add the `support.v7.appcompat` library. I'm able to add the jar to my project, but I can't find any way to add the relevant resources. I keep getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.` even though I've added `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` to the `<manifest>` element of my `AndroidManifest.xml` per one of the earlier, seemingly-relevant search results. I've also added `android.library.reference.1=<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` to my `local.properties`, to no avail.

Can someone please instruct me on how to add this library from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however, the official documentation doesn't support that

The [general Android library project instructions](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) should work fine.

> I'm able to add the jar to my project

That's not what you are supposed to do.

> I've also added android.library.reference.1=<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat to my local.properties, to no avail.

That goes in `project.properties`, not `local.properties`. And it needs to be a relative path, for some crazy reason, so make sure you set it up that way.

Personally, I'd recommend that you budget the time to move to Gradle.

---

It turns out that there were two tiers of problems. In addition to getting the command-line build files set up properly, the theme wasn't registered quite the right way.

If you are going to directly reference `Theme.AppCompat` in the manifest, it either:

- should be on the `<application>` element, or
- should be on every `<activity>` element where the activity inherits from `AppCompatActivity`

Or, if you are going to stick with your own `AppTheme` that inherits from `Theme.AppCompat`, you need to ensure that you adjust all of the relevant style resources. For example, you might adjust `AppBaseTheme` in `res/values/styles.xml` to inherit from `Theme.AppCompat` (and then have `AppTheme` inherits from `AppBaseTheme`), per commonly-generated code. However, there may also be definitions of `AppBaseTheme` in other directories (e.g., `res/values-v11/styles.xml`) that need to be adjusted as well.

Comment: I've tried both `project.properties` and `local.properties`, same result with both. I'm using the relative path.

Comment: @weberc2: Considering that Eclipse uses `project.properties`, and it works, I feel quite confident that `project.properties` is the correct answer. Also, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/AppCompat) builds and runs fine on my development machine using Ant.

Comment: I switched back to `project.properties` and removed the .jar file from my `libs/` dir. I took care to follow the instructions to which you linked in your post, but the result was the same. I'm building with `ant debug` and deploying with `adb install -r ./bin/MyFirstApp-debug.apk`; is there a chance something isn't being correctly updated?

Comment: @weberc2: Do you have `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` at the `<application>` level? If not, do you have it for *all* of your `ActionBarActivity` subclasses? Also, did you adjust all relevant style resources to reflect the `Theme.AppCompat` change?

Comment: Nope, my `android:theme` was in the manifest level, per some other internet resource. Moving it to the `<application>` level resolved the issue. Thanks for your help. If you care to update your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt responses and correct solution, accepted and upvoted.